# Most consecutive positive integers using two 1s

Tags: mathematics, calculation-puzzle, formation-of-numbers

Using two 1s, try to come up with the most consecutive positive integers.

Allowed operations:

- Addition
- Subtraction
- Multiplication
- Division
- Concatenation
- Square Root
- Radical
- Factorial
- Floor and Ceiling Functions
- Decimal Point

Comment: Isn't there a conjecture that with only factorial, square root and floor, and starting with any *single* number >1, you can form all positive integers? If so, this seems like one that could go on for ever...

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan It'd have to be $>2$, because $2!=2$, floor decreases and square root makes closer to 1.

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan ... and floor yields an integer.

Comment: Oops, yes, I meant >2.

Comment: Do you happen to recall the name of this conjecture?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let's try (feel free to add on or correct, this is community wiki):

> $1=1\times1$
>
> $2=1+1$
>
> $3=\left\lfloor\sqrt{11}\right\rfloor$
>
> $4=\left\lceil\sqrt{11}\right\rceil$
>
> $5=\left\lfloor\sqrt{\sqrt{\left(\left\lfloor\sqrt{11}\right\rfloor!\right)!}}\right\rfloor$
>
> $6=\left\lfloor\sqrt{11}\right\rfloor!$
>
> $7=\left\lceil\sqrt{\sqrt{11}!}!\right\rceil$
>
> $8=\left\lfloor\sqrt{\sqrt{\sqrt{11!}}}\right\rfloor$
>
> $9=\left\lfloor\sqrt{11}!\right\rfloor$
>
> $10=\left\lceil\sqrt{11}!\right\rceil$
>
> $11=11$
>
> $12=\left\lceil\sqrt{\sqrt{\sqrt{\sqrt{\sqrt{\left\lceil\sqrt{\sqrt{\sqrt{\sqrt{(\left\lceil\sqrt{11}\space\right\rceil!)!}}}}\right\rceil!}}}}}\right\rceil$
>
> $13=\left\lceil\sqrt{\sqrt{\sqrt{\left\lceil\sqrt{\sqrt{\sqrt{\sqrt{\sqrt{\left\lceil\sqrt{\sqrt{\sqrt{\sqrt{(\left\lceil\sqrt{11}\space\right\rceil!)!}}}}\right\rceil!}}}}}\right\rceil}}}\right\rceil$
>
> $14=\sqrt{\sqrt{\left\lfloor\sqrt{\sqrt{\left\lceil\sqrt{\sqrt{\sqrt{(1\div(.1))!}}}\right\rceil!}}\right\rfloor!}}$

Comment: I found a way for 12 but it's just a hassle to write it down. We can go all the way to infinity without much problem.

Comment: Getting past **10** was the hard part.

Comment: @humn I simplified my 10 as well as the 7 and 9. Looks much better now. But I guess 11 is a good number to stop this... I am not going any higher lol.

Comment: Anyone want to write a program for this...?

Comment: This is turning into a ridiculous open-ended mathematics exercise. It seems likely that given an unlimited number of factorials, square roots, floor and ceilings, you could express the values of all positive integers.

Comment: Reminds me of the Collatz Conjecture, you have increasing and decreasing rules that seem to take you on arbitrarily long journeys up and down through number space.